# Trouble with class inheritance in C++ SDL

Tags: c++, class, sdl, state-machine

My program is throwing an "expression must have class type" on me and I'm not sure why. I've created a class for a button that I'm using, it has rectangle boundaries, and a sprite sheet to clip from. I use this class inside my `Title` class `GameState`. It allows me to load the sprites that I declare in the button class, but not start to define the SDL_Rect. I want to define the `X` value of `Title_Button.button.x` But when I type that line is claims that the expression must have a class type. What's the problem here?

```
/*CLASSES*/

class GameState
{
public:
    virtual void event();
    virtual void logic();
    virtual void render();
    virtual ~GameState(){};
};

class Button
{
public:
    SDL_Rect *button = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* button_sprite = NULL;
};

Button::Button()
{

}

class Title : public GameState
{
private:
public:
    void event();
    void logic();
    void render();
    Title();
    ~Title();
};

Title::Title()
{

    Button Title_Button;
    Title_Button.button_sprite = load_image("Start.png");
    Title_Button.button.x = 250;
}
```

Does the class `Button` have to also inherit GameState? Or what?

Comment: `Title_Button.button->x`, perhaps? Seeing as `Button::button` is a pointer.

Comment: It would be very helpful to include the exact error message and some indication which lines of code are causing the error.

Comment: "Expression must have class type" On the line that says "Title_Button.button.x = 250;"

Comment: Igor has the correct answer! Thank you!

Comment: try defining Button Class before GameState class